# Analogue of Blaschke products for the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation, blaschke-products

It is well-known that the biholomorphic self-maps of the upper half-plane are Mobius transformations $$\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ with $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $ad-bc=1.$

Also, on the unit disk, **holomorphic self-maps that extend continuously to the boundary** are the [finite Blaschke products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product). These are a finite product of disk automorphisms up to a rotation.

I would like to see some kind of nice representation theorem for holomorphic self-maps of the upper half-plane. I tried the composition $\varphi B\varphi^{-1},$ where $\varphi$ is a Mobius transformation from the unit disk to the upper half-plane and $B$ is a finite Blaschke product. Even for degree two Blaschke product $B,$ this gives a complicated-looking formula from which I cannot see anything.

- Is there a nice way to represent holomorphic self-maps of the upper half-plane? I would like to see this with a proof.

**Added later**: I conjecture that one possible representation is $$f(z)+\sum_{1\le j\le n}\dfrac{c_j}{z-a_j}$$ where $a_j\in\mathbb{R}, c_j\in\mathbb{R}^-$ and $f$ is some holomorphic self-map on the closed upper half plane. For example, $f(z)=az+b$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}^+,b\in\mathbb{R}$ works. See the comment section for a vague explanation of how I arrived at this. What is the most general form of $f,$ and how can we prove this in general?

Comment: This reference may be useful: Chapter on '$H^{p}$ spaces for the upper half plane' in Introduction to $H^{p}$ spaces by Koosis.

Comment: The Blaschke products for the upper half plane are $(\frac{z-i}{z+i})^m\Pi \frac{|z_n^2+1|}{z_n^2+1}\frac{z-z_n}{z-\bar z_n}$, where the Blaschke condition is $\sum \frac{\Im z_n}{z_n^2+1} < \infty$ for all the zeroes $z_n \ne i$

Comment: @Conrad: The codomain of the map seems to be the unit disk. I am looking for maps from the upper half plane to itself.

Comment: That's true but you just have to compose any of these with the standard mobius transform from the unit disc to the upper half plane and get your maps - the above form is useful because is simple, while otherwise the form is messy unless one has a degree one map so a mobius transform; it all depends on what questions you are interested in but I am not sure anything simpler than the above can be got explicitly;

Comment: @Conrad: Thank you very much for your reply. I feel that instead of zeros, one can consider the poles of such a function. All of them ought to be on the real axis by Schwarz's reflection principle. So the resulting function has the form $f(z)+\sum_{j}\dfrac{c_j}{(z-a_j)^{m_j}}.$ Then somehow invoke Liouville's theorem.

Comment: At least when $f=\text{some real constant},$ all $m_j=1$ and all $c_j\in\mathbb{R}^+$ this maps the upper half plane to itself because $\Im\left(\dfrac{1}{z-a}\right)=\dfrac{\Im(z)}{|z-a|^2}$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}.$ But I'm not sure what other conditions should be there, and how this can be proven in general.

Comment: In fact, $f$ can be a linear function of the form $az+b$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$ as adding such a function does not change the sign of the imaginary part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analytic functions mapping the upper half plane $H$ into itself are called the Pick functions and they have the form

$$f(z)=kz+\alpha-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{z\gamma+1}{z-\gamma}\mu(d\gamma)$$ where $k\geq 0$ and $\mu$ is a positive bounded mesure. Furthermore, there are such that $\lim_{y\to 0} \Im f(x+iy)=0$ -thus preserving the real axis -if and only if $\mu$ is purely singular- this includes atomic measures which are what you need and also Cantor like ones. If $\mu$ is a finite sum of Dirac, you get the analogs of Blaschke products.

I had to use these Pick functions for writing 'Which functions preserve Cauchy laws' Proc. Amer. Math. Soc,  1977, Vol 67 pages 277-286. I was unaware of Pick functions and a bit painfully I had, like you, to move from the disk to $H$ where the necessary theory for the disk is developped in the Rudin's book Real and complex analysis. Only later I discovered the excellent book on Pick functions by Donoghue, 1974 Monotone Matrix Functions and Analytic Continuation, Springer.